# Can't Shrink Ubuntu lvm2 Partition to Dual Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

My laptop has a 256 GB SSD that I installed Ubuntu onto when I got it. I guess I encrypted the drive and made it an lvm2.

I don't know what that means but when I try to shrink it, it only allows me to shrink about 50 MB. Here's the partition table:

```
Partition   MountPt     TOTAL   FREE    TYPE
nvme0n1p1   /boot/efi   512 MB  505 MB  fat32
nvme0n1p2   /boot       723 MB  544 MB  ext4
nvme0n1p3   ubuntu-vg   237 GB   48 GB  lvm2 pv encrypted
```

I've tried KVPM and KDE Partition Managers but they have the same issue, saying I can't reduce the size of the partition.

I want to create a dual boot with Windows. So how can I free up the free space on the partition to do this? I don't want to ruin my filesystem or anything so I need pretty clear instructions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Replaced https://i.stack.imgur.com/EirvA.png with a text table for the sanity of those trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

The complexities of [lvm2](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) [(man page)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/lvm.8.html) requires you go into the lvm2 partition and [shrink its filesystem](https://www.rootusers.com/lvm-resize-how-to-decrease-an-lvm-partition/) size before you can shrink the lvm2 partition itself, unlike the more user-friendly ext4. That requires you boot from a LiveUSB.

1. As per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions make a complete backup of your system and verify the backup matches the source.
2. Make a second complete backup of your system, then verify the second backup to make sure that backup is also good.
3. Make a LiveUSB with persistance.
4. Boot from that LiveUSB and follow the steps at  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions
5. Once you have completed the above, then you can follow [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) to add Windows to your Ubuntu system.